What are these rectangular notes?
I was reading a piano sheet and noticed what seem to be rectangular dotted quarter notes and half notes during some glissandi:


In contrast, there are other glissandi in the sheet that use typical round notes. Could anyone explain the difference?
For context, the composer is from Japan, in case this notation happens to be region specific.

Related: What is this open, vertical rectangular symbol?

This symbol is the same as the one discussed in the post @ElementsInSpace linked to. The only difference being the fact that the cluster is played into a glissando. Basically run your entire palm over the keyboard.

@Aaron Got it, thank you. One small question, could you explain what the symbol below the dotted quarter note and above the half note is?

Those symbols look like asterisks (probably linking to a footnote at the bottom of the page that explains the notation).

I agree with @ElementsInSpace. See What is this quadruple-dotted X above the staff?.
